# I'm an electrical engineer. How can I describe that in a CV?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

I would like to describe my job in a CV. What is the best way to do it?

My study (experience) is about generators that produces a very high power, Large transformers, Power Transmission lines, large three phase motors and so on.

> 1. Does the term "**Electrical Power Engineering**" describe my job?
> 2. Should I use **Electrical** or **Electric**?
> 3. Should I use **Specialization** or **speciality** or **Department**?

What should I write in my CV to clarify these three questions?

1. Specialization: Electrical Power Engineering
2. Specialization: Electric Power Engineering
3. Department: Electrical Power Engineering
4. Department: Electric Power Engineering
5. speciality: Electrical Power Engineering
6. speciality: Electric Power Engineering

Tell me if you have better suggestions.

Comment: This might be better asked on Workplace or EE... I don't know anything about EE but I'm pretty sure "Electrical Power Engineering" isn't a thing that an employer is going to take to mean what you're saying. You'd probably be better off saying "I have a degree in Electrical Engineering and my work has been specialized in generators that... ". There's no reason to reduce your explanation to a three-word title that doesn't make sense.

Comment: "Electric Power Engineer" works for your description since you seem to be based in that power production industry.  Your specialisation would be "transmission" (generators, transformers, power lines)  as opposed to power plant design and operation.  I'm guessing you work for a large utility company or an outsourced third party. "Electrical Engineer" usually means integrated circuit production and design, which is not you.

Comment: "Power engineering" or "Power systems enginnering" seems to be accepted terms for this: "a subfield of energy engineering and electrical engineering". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_engineering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I hear the term **electrical engineering**, what I typically think of are things like transistors, integrated circuits and motherboards—basically things that have to do with microprocessors, computers and stuff like that. Electrical engineers are often called EEs (pronounced: double Es) in tech lingo.

Things that have to do with transformers and electrical power transmission lines are part of the field that we call **industrial electricity**. So, you are probably **an industrial electrician/engineer**.

Example:

> — What is your specialization? What do you do?
>   — I'm an industrial electrician/engineer. I specialize in industrial power engineering.

I'm pretty sure the descriptions I gave you here will generally work just fine, but once again, you'd better double check all that.